# TFS Team or Code Management of PHP

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

How can I use TFS power tools to commit php code. I want to commit the code using windows explorer. As we can do using svn or git hub. Please guide me in this regard

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And did you install the shell extension when you installed the power tools? If so committing should simply be a matter of right clicking the folder and choosing to check in your changes.

Comment: I have installed power tools shell extension. But did not get any changes on windows explorer

Comment: restart your machine to get the shell extension running, also ensure that you have a workspace mapped between TFS and your local folder, you should then be able to right click in windows explorer and choose the TFS option from the context menu

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I have confusion that how can I map my local folder to TFS folder. I will thankful to you for your detailed answer.